# $http angularjs return nao esperado

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

## Descrição

Estou implementando uma requisição $http com angular. Quero retornar os objetos do banco.

#### Código

CompanyService.coffee

```
angular.module('vaultfactor').factory 'CompanyService', ($http, $q) ->
getCompanies: ->
    promise = $http.get "/companies"
    company = promise.then((response)->
        if typeof response.data == 'object'
            console.log(response.data)
            return response.data
        else
            return $q.reject(response.data)
    (response)->
        $q.reject(response.data))
```

main_ctrl.coffee

```
angular.module('vaultfactor').controller 'HomeCtrl', ($scope, $rootScope, 
    $location, $http, CompanyService) ->
        console.log(CompanyService.getCompanies())
```

### Problema

O objeto retornado não é o modelo que esperava.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dando um console.log em meu **response.data** antes do return ele me devolve exatamente oque preciso. assim: ( Está sendo passado nas dependencias o $q, postei uma imagem mais antiga. )

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Console.log:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Oque estou passando de errado no return do meu success?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente desta maneira no service:

```
angular.module('vaultfactor').factory 'CompanyService', ($http, $q) ->
getCompanies: ->
    $http.get "/companies"
```

E onde for usar a lista:

```
angular.module('vaultfactor').controller 'HomeCtrl', ($scope, $rootScope, 
    $location, $http, CompanyService) ->
        promise = CompanyService.getCompanies()
        company = promise.then((response)->
            if typeof response.data == 'object'
                console.log(response.data)
                return response.data
            else
                return $q.reject(response.data)
```

Lembre se que isso funciona se o retorno for um objeto, se for array você precisa trocar o get por query como no exemplo abaixo:

```
$http.query "/companies"
```

Comment: Funciono perfeitamente!